# My reconciliation VBA macro takes too long to run when the data is in the thousands

Tags: vba

I have a task that requires me to reconcile two sheets of data. I have reformatted them both to have the same format from Column A to M and use the below code to run the reconciliation
It is fine when the data is small but when it gets to thousands of lines, it took 30 min just to run. Is there a way to optimize this code?

The idea is reconcile 2 worksheets then all the matched data go to the 'Matched' worksheet and the unmatched goes to the unmatched worksheet

```
Dim report_exLR As Long
Dim report_inLR As Long
Dim report_exrng As Range
Dim report_inrng As Range
Set ws_rexternal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reformat External")
Set ws_rinternal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reformat Internal")
Set ws_unmatched = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unmatched")
Set ws_matched = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Matched")
ex_LR = ws_rexternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
in_LR = ws_rinternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'concatenate all relevant criteria into one column
For a = 2 To ex_LR
    ws_rexternal.Range("T" & a) = ws_rexternal.Range("A" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("B" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("C" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("D" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("E" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("F" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("G" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("H" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("I" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("J" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("K" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("L" & a) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("M" & a)
Next a

For b = 2 To ex_LR
    ws_rinternal.Range("T" & b) = ws_rexternal.Range("A" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("B" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("C" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("D" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("E" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("F" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("G" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("H" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("I" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("J" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("K" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("L" & b) & "," & ws_rexternal.Range("M" & b)
Next b

'start reconciliation
For a = 2 To ex_LR
For b = 2 To in_LR
If ws_rexternal.Range("T" & a) = ws_rinternal.Range("T" & b) Then

ws_rexternal.Range(Cells(a, 1).Address, Cells(a, 14).Address).Copy Destination:=ws_matched.Range(Cells(a, 1).Address, Cells(a, 14).Address)
ws_rinternal.Range(Cells(b, 1).Address, Cells(b, 14).Address).Copy Destination:=ws_matched.Range(Cells(a, 16).Address, Cells(a, 30).Address)
ws_matched.Cells(a, 15).Value = "Matched"
ws_matched.Cells(a, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
ws_rexternal.Rows(a).ClearContents
ws_rinternal.Rows(b).ClearContents
End If

Next b
Next a

'reformat the unmatched and matched
For d = ex_LR To 1 Step -1
    Set ex_Row = ws_rexternal.Rows(d)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ex_Row) = 0 Then
        ws_rexternal.Rows(d).Delete
    End If
Next d

For e = in_LR To 1 Step -1
    Set in_Row = ws_rinternal.Rows(e)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(in_Row) = 0 Then
        ws_rinternal.Rows(e).Delete
    End If
Next e

report_exLR = ws_rexternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
report_inLR = ws_rinternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set report_exrng = ws_rexternal.Range("A1:A" & report_exLR)
report_exrng.EntireRow.Copy ws_unmatched.Cells(1, 1)
Set report_inrng = ws_rinternal.Range("A1:A" & report_inLR)
report_inrng.EntireRow.Copy ws_unmatched.Cells(ex_LR, 1).Offset(5, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: The typical response is to move the data into VBA arrays, do you calculations and then write the final result array back to Excel.

Comment: Are the rows unique within each worksheet?

Comment: If rows are identical then do you need to copy both matched rows to the "matched" sheet?

Comment: All rows are not unique, there can be the same, in which both sheets will match on one line and the duplicates will try to match the second and so on. If rows are identical then I need to copy both matched rows to the matched sheet

Comment: So if one unique row on "external" matches two rows on "internal", the first pair of records are copied to "match", and the remaining record from "internal" goes to "unmatched" ?

Comment: That's correct  yes. It could also be vice versa such as two identical rows on "external" and one row on "internal", in which case the first pair matched and the remaining recors goes to unmatched

Comment: Deleted my answer as it had some serious issues...   Will try another approach tomorrow

Comment: Do you need copy/paste (are there formats etc which need to be maintained) or would direct transfer of the values be enough to meet your needs here?

Comment: The report will need to be able to show which row on "external" is matched to which row on "internal" on the "matched" worksheet. And all the leftover items from both "external" and "internal" will be copy/pasted to an "unmatched worksheet" in two separate tables. I guess copy/paste would be better since the items involved contain strings and numbers since it involves currency matching.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is probably a lot more complex than it needs to be, but it seems to work OK.

It would be *much* simpler to just flag the data *in-place* as matched/unmatched, with a pointer to the matching row on the other sheet.

```vb
Sub FormatExcel()
    
    Dim report_exLR As Long, ws_rexternal As Worksheet, ws_unmatched As Worksheet
    Dim report_inLR As Long, ws_rinternal As Worksheet, ws_matched As Worksheet
    Dim report_exrng As Range, report_inrng As Range
    Dim rngInt As Range, rngExt As Range, k, rw As Range, t, rwMatch As Long
    Dim rngIntKeys As Range, rngExtKeys As Range, m, rng As Range, n As Long
    Dim rngUnmatchedInt As Range, rngUnmatchedExt As Range
    
    Setup
    t = Timer
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws_rexternal = .Worksheets("Reformat External")
        Set ws_rinternal = .Worksheets("Reformat Internal")
        Set ws_unmatched = .Worksheets("Unmatched")
        Set ws_matched = .Worksheets("Matched")
    End With
    
    'clear previous data
    ws_unmatched.Cells.Clear
    ws_matched.Cells.Clear
    
    'source data ranges
    Set rngInt = ws_rinternal.Range("A2:M" & ws_rinternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngExt = ws_rexternal.Range("A2:M" & ws_rexternal.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'speed up copy/paste
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'generate all keys for Internal rows in ColT
    For Each rw In rngInt.Rows
        rw.EntireRow.Columns("T").Value = RowKey(rw)
    Next rw
    Set rngIntKeys = rngInt.EntireRow.Columns("T") 'range with keys
    Debug.Print "Generated keys", Timer - t
    
    rwMatch = 1
    For Each rw In rngExt.Rows
        If rw.Row Mod 100 = 0 Then Debug.Print "Row: " & rw.Row, Timer - t
        m = Application.Match(RowKey(rw), rngIntKeys, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then                      'got match on "internal" sheet?
            rwMatch = rwMatch + 1
            rw.Copy ws_matched.Cells(rwMatch, "A")
            ws_matched.Cells(rwMatch, "N").Value = "Matched"
            rngInt.Rows(m).Copy ws_matched.Cells(rwMatch, "P")
            rngIntKeys.Cells(m).ClearContents       'remove matched key from T
        Else
            BuildRange rngUnmatchedExt, rw   'collect unmatched external row
        End If
    Next rw
    Debug.Print "Copied matches", Timer - t
    
    'copy unmatched external
    If Not rngUnmatchedExt Is Nothing Then
        rngUnmatchedExt.Copy ws_unmatched.Range("A1")
    End If
    
    'copy unmatched internal
    Set rngIntKeys = rngInt.EntireRow.Columns("T")
    For n = 1 To rngExt.Rows.Count
        If Len(rngIntKeys.Cells(n).Value) > 0 Then
            BuildRange rngUnmatchedInt, rngExt.Rows(n)
        End If
    Next n
    If Not rngUnmatchedInt Is Nothing Then
        rngUnmatchedInt.Copy _
            ws_unmatched.Cells(ws_unmatched.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 5, 1)
    End If
    Debug.Print "Copied non-matches", Timer - t
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

'generate a "key" by concatenating all cell values in `rng` with "|"
Function RowKey(rng As Range) As String
    RowKey = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value)), "|")
End Function

'build up a range from sub-ranges
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

For completeness here's the sub I used to reset the sheets and create sample data:

```vb
'reset the sheets and create some sample data
Sub Setup()
    Const ROWSN As Long = 1000                  '# of rows to create
    Const RNDV As String = "=ROUND(rand()*5,0)" 'adjust to change chance of matched rows
    Dim ws_rexternal As Worksheet, ws_unmatched As Worksheet
    Dim ws_rinternal As Worksheet, ws_matched As Worksheet
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws_rexternal = .Worksheets("Reformat External")
        Set ws_rinternal = .Worksheets("Reformat Internal")
        Set ws_unmatched = .Worksheets("Unmatched")
        Set ws_matched = .Worksheets("Matched")
    End With
    'clar all sheets
    ws_unmatched.Cells.Clear
    ws_matched.Cells.Clear
    ws_rexternal.Cells.Clear
    ws_rinternal.Cells.Clear
    
    'ws_rexternal.Range ("A2:M1000")
    With ws_rexternal.Range("A2:C2").Resize(ROWSN)
        .Formula = RNDV
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    ws_rexternal.Range("D2:M2").Resize(ROWSN).Value = "blah"
    With ws_rinternal.Range("A2:C2").Resize(ROWSN)
        .Formula = RNDV
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    ws_rinternal.Range("D2:M2").Resize(ROWSN).Value = "blah"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! However the rows are not unique. I can have multiple shapes of the same row, in which case the macro should be able to match them together and show the leftover duplciate as unmatched